# Lambda causes compilation error

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to fill a vector container with objects using the standard library's `std::generate` function:

```
  vector<className> table(20);
  generate(table.begin(), table.end(), [&] { return className(); } );
```

I get the following errors:

```
Expected primary expression before '[' token.
Expected primary expression before ']' token.
```

I know that `[&]` is added to get a reference of the object being returned, but I don't know where the brackets come from (I've seen this in several examples on how to use `generate`).

Some explanation and demonstration of where the mistake comes from would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Lambda expressions require C++11, which I wasn't using. There is no need for `()` after `[&]`.

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11 ?

Comment: Please provide a full, minimal example that reproduces your problem so that we can compile it ourselves.

Comment: Which compiler and version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It seems you are not compiling with C++11 support enabled, i.e. `-std=c++11` is missing, if you are using `clang` or `gcc`
2. The brackets define how variables outside the lambda are captured. I.e. `[&]` makes it capture variables by reference, and `[=]` copies every variable you access.

As reference for lambdas and their capture list, you can use [Lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Lambda functions are also supported in Visual Studio [since the 2010 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603(v=vs.100).aspx), in case the OP is using Visual Studio. It would be nice to know which compiler and version he is using